# JS: get hostname from url , regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to get hostname from set of urls that my webapp can encounter with.
The desired output should be something like `http://localhost/Webapp/`, ending at `/Webapp/`  and everything after that should be removed.

Kindly note that I dont want to use word Webapp in regex as this name is dynamic and used for demo/testcase only.this can be anything , not harcoded.

In real example I am using `location.href.replace(/index.+/g, "").replace(/#.+/g, "")`
and I want to keep only hostname ending at`Webapp/`.

**Problem:**
my solution seems to working fine except `"http://localhost/Webapp/#"` is not working correctly ? why is that ? see fiddle below

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/um0uqb8v/
**JS:**

```
var getHost = function (url) {
    return url.replace(/index.+/g, "").replace(/#.+/g, "")
};
var urls = [
     "http://localhost/Webapp/",
    "http://localhost/Webapp/#",
    "http://localhost:8080/Webapp/#sdf#dfgdf#fdg",
    "12.168.1.1:8080/Webapp/index.html#",
    "https://localhost/Webapp/index.html#ab#bg",
    "https://localhost/Webapp/index.html"
];
//Print all urls
$.each(urls, function () {
    $("<p/>").text(getHost(this)).appendTo($(".test"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try removing anything after the last slash (files and hash-es):

```
var getHost = function (url) {
    return url.replace(/\/[^/]*?$/, '/');
};
```

And [here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um0uqb8v/1/).

Answer (score 4):

Use `url.match(/https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/);`

**EDIT:**

It returns an array where the 1st element is the host with protocol and the 2nd without.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit of a trick you can use to get the browser to extract the hostname for you.

```
var getHost = function (url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a.hostname;
};
```

It also appears you want the path as well. You can access it with the `pathname` property of the `a` element. If you're doing that, you ought to rename the function to something like `getHostAndPath()`.

Comment: @django no, it doesn't.